# Closed-form expression for an asymmetric triangle wave?

Tags: matlab, math, wolfram-mathematica

I am working on a project and I would like to plot a continuous, repeating, asymmetric triangle wave. I have the expression for the symmetric kind, but for the asymmetry, I have only been able to find it as a fourier series but need it in a form that uses the floor (or nearest-integer) function.

I need the asymmetry to independently control the slope of the rising and falling edge.

I am programming in Matlab, but that doesn't really matter since I need the mathematical expression and not some built-in function or clever approximation. I need the expression in order to do some hand derivation and the simulation is just to confirm.

Physically I am trying to plot the current waveform in an inductor for duty cycles not equal to 50%

Answer (score 1):

Given: `Phase, Period, AMin, AMax, RisingTime`

[image]

```
 LocalT = Frac((T + Phase)/ Period)  
 //fractional part Frac(x) = x - RoundedToMinusInfinity(x)
 //Frac(1.3)=0.3, Frac(-1.3) = 0.7

 if LocalT <= RisingTime then
    Y = AMin + (AaAx - AMin) * (LocalT / RisingTime)
 else
    Y = AMax -  (AMax - AMin) * (LocalT - RisingTime) / (Period - RisingTime)
```